# JSF PrimeFaces select on google map

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to select **via mouse click** a rectangle part of google map using JSF PimeFaces `<p:gmap>` or any other JSF solution and to get it top-left and bottom-right coordinates, like here in jQuery sample: http://jsfiddle.net/JsAJA/3/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think that without using javascript it is impossible.

You can access google map in primeface component in the JS and then manually add all listeners to handle with your rectangle:

```
//<![CDATA[
function initMap(){
    var map = gmtls.getMap();
    //and now add listeners like:
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousedown', function(mEvent) {
        //and body of the listener
    });   
}
//]]>

<h:body onload="initMap();">
    <center>
        <h:form>  
            <p:gmap widgetVar="gmtls" center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="hybrid" style="width:600px;height:400px" />
        </h:form>  
    </center>
</h:body>
```